# Foreign Key Constraint: Uniqueness vs. Data Redundancy

Tags: database-design

Say we have four tables (column names in parentheses):

- `types` (`type_name`)
- `parameters` (`type_name`, `parameter_name`)
- `instances` (`instance_id`, `type_name`)
- `instance_parameters` (`instance_id`, `parameter_name`, `parameter_value`)

In English: Types can define parameters. Instances of a type can set values for the predefined parameters of their type. We have (the obvious) FK constraints for all `type_name` as well as `instance_id` columns.

Now I would like to make sure that rows in `instance_parameters` reference existing `parameter_name`s in `parameters`. A classical FK constraint is not possible because the `type_name` is implied by the `instance_id` and thus missing in order to reference a unique key in the parent table `parameters`.

How can I accomplish this without adding the redundant information of `type_name` to the `instance_parameters` table?

Comment: This is a faq. If you want to do this declaratively in SQL you put the type in the table & the FK.

Comment: @philipxy Thanks for your answer but as I wrote in the question, I would like to avoid adding a `type_name` column to `instance_parameters` because it's redundant information. Isn't there another way?

Comment: SQL declarative constraints implemented by current DBMSs are very few. Any other constraining must use triggers. Again, a faq. PS "Redundant" is neither good nor bad per se (and doesn't even have a specific meaning), engineering involves the big picture.

Comment: Thanks I will think about this. I meant "redundant" in a way that an implied and already available information is repeated and thus violates the DRY principle which in my experience applies to data just as well as it applies to logic.
I'm neither a relational DB design pro and I think I will have to look into a "triggers" approach first.

Comment: Sure. In case it's not clear the idea/idiom here is that for the clarity, simplicity & performance benefits it's better to add data & a constraint instead of using triggers. PS I know what you are meaning by redundancy here but in general the term means nothing in particular & justifies nothing in particular. PS Please before considering posting read the manual/reference & google any error message & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. Reflect research.

Comment: I actually did research and consulted the manuals (in my case Postgres and SQLAlchemy) but I think due to not knowing the right terms/phrasing or the right sources, I did not find this question anywhere and less was I under the impression that this is a FAQ. Please feel free to mark this post as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

The way I understand the story, as close to the original schema as I could get it:

```
-- Type TYP exists.
--
type {TYP}
  PK {TYP}
```

```
-- Parameter PAR of type TYP exists.
--
parameter {PAR, TYP}
       PK {PAR}
       SK {PAR, TYP}

FK {TYP} REFERENCES type {TYP}
```

```
-- Instance INS of type TYP exists.
-- 
instance {INS, TYP}
      PK {INS}
      SK {INS, TYP}

FK {TYP} REFERENCES type {TYP}
```

```
-- Instance INS of type TYP, of parameter PAR (of that type),
-- has value VAL. 
--
instance_parameter {INS, PAR, TYP, VAL}
                PK {INS}

FK1 {INS, TYP} REFERENCES instance  {INS, TYP}
FK2 {PAR, TYP} REFERENCES parameter {PAR, TYP}
```

---

Most likely you would want to simplify:

```
-- Type TYP exists.
--
type {TYP}
  PK {TYP}
```

```
-- Parameter PAR of type TYP exists.
--
parameter {PAR, TYP}
       PK {PAR}

FK {TYP} REFERENCES type {TYP}
```

```
-- Instance INS of parameter PAR has value VAL.
-- 
instance {INS, PAR, VAL}
      PK {INS}

FK {PAR} REFERENCES parameter {PAR}
```

---

Note:

```
All attributes (columns) NOT NULL

PK = Primary Key
AK = Alternate Key   (Unique)
SK = Proper Superkey (Unique)
FK = Foreign Key
```

Comment: Thanks Damir for your answer. I think you got the schema right in the first place. 
The detail I wanted to avoid, if possible, is repeating the TYP in instance_parameter as it is implied information in INS. However this does seem to be necessary, as @philipxy already pointed out in his question comments.
Your simplification is unfortunately oversimplified as there is a distinction intended between instances of a type and instance parameters.